# What's an efficient way to change the post status of many posts at once?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, plugin-development

I'm looking for an efficient way to change the post status on many posts at once. I have a custom post type that I'm using as a means to store content that must be approved by a moderator before being published. I'm trying to give the moderator the ability to "approve all" or "reject all" on a fairly large number of posts (100-200 would be common).

The best solution I've come up with is to make an ajax call that sends a list of post id's to the server, which loops through them calling the below function:

```
wp_update_post(array('ID'=> $post_id, 'post_status' => 'publish' ))
```

This results in a query to the DB for each post, however, and it's much slower than I'd like. Ideally, I'd be able to make a query that changes the post status to 'publish' on all of the post ID's in the list at once, but I can't find any means to do this.

Comment: I don't have time to dig into this right now, but you might look at how the core Bulk Edit tool works. Not that core is perfect... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is the safe way, and the way I'd recommend. To my knowledge, there is no Core function to bulk update only single values in the `$wpdb->posts` table, so to do that you'd need to write your own SQL...

```
$ids = array(); // your IDs; I am assuming these to be validated and sanitized
$wpdb->query("UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET post_status = 'publish' WHERE ID IN  (".implode(',',$ids)).")");
```

You might be able to do the same with [`$wpdb->update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) but I rarely use that method, so I am not sure. (A comment below indicates that it is not possible.) Check the Codex and play with it if you want.

**I would recommend not doing either**, though, and continuing to use `wp_update_post`. If you skip around the Core functions you also skip around numerous actions and filters, and may cause yourself unintended consequences or other frustrations later on.

Comment: I second your thought on continuing to use `wp_update_post`. Hopefully taking away your unsureness about using `$wpdb->update`: this is not possible, as you can neither use the `IN`-operator (the `WHERE`-clause will be automatically generated as `[column] = [value]`, i.e. you can not specify the operator used) nor use the `OR`-operator on the different `WHERE`-clauses (the `WHERE`-clauses are automatically joined with `AND`s).

Comment: Would there be a better approach than using IDs, then? All of the posts in question are of the same custom post type and have the same post status. Is there a way to select them all using this criteria that's faster than what I'm doing (effectively: WHERE post_type = custom_post_type AND post_status = status)?

Comment: No. The `ID` is probably the single best field to use. You can try using additional conditions but I doubt you'd see a significant improvement. The slow-down is going to be the insert, not the select.

Comment: Using MySQL Workbench, I watched the activity on the MySQL server when using a couple methods to do this. If I do a loop over all the post ids and call wp_update_post() on 100 posts, my server deals with over 500 queries per second.

Alternatively, if I use my own function and pass it a post id and do the following, the server only shows activity of 8 queries per second and completes the change noticeably faster:

$wpdb->query( 
 $wpdb->prepare( 
  "UPDATE $wpdb->posts
   SET post_status = 'publish'
   WHERE ID = %s",
  $post_id));

What risks are involved by doing it this way?